# Way to update user while code is executing?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm creating a SwiftUI multiplatform app in XCode and I have a section of my code that hangs. I want to update the user so they know what's happening and are willing to wait. I originally planned to have an alert with text that changed and then planned to have a Text element that updated. In both cases this isn't shown until after the code executes and as such only shows the final message (normally the success done message unless an error made it end sooner).

Is there anyway I can have a visible message to the user through an alert or SwiftUI element that is updated right away and thus will be helpful?

Comment: It depends on whether the operation we're waiting for is determinate (we know at each instant what percentage of progress has been made) or indeterminate. Which is it?

Comment: Looks like you need to take your lengthy process off the main thread and show your message before calling this lengthy process.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the alert isn't even shown until after the code executes is bad and incorrect. This suggests that you are doing something lengthy on the main thread, and that is an absolute no-no. You are freezing the interface and you risk the WatchDog process crashing your app before the user's very eyes. If something takes time, do it in the background.

Comment: So look into doing an async process? And lock the button (that set it off) until finished so the user doesn't click it several times? It's a set number of tasks so I was planning on updating the user when each section is done